# ElementList, can't find elements in file?

Tags: python, xml

I am going through tutorials on ElementList in Python with this file and all the operations work fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

I can find any bit of data I want in this, with the root being data. I got this here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Eg:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    print child.tag
    print child.attrib
```

This would give:

```
country
{'name': 'Liechtenstein'}
country
{'name': 'Singapore'}
country
{'name': 'Panama'}
```

However in the xml file I have to read and use I can't seem to get any of the data that I want. Here is the file: http://pastebin.com/b5bwrSFU

If I run the same code I get:

```
{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}VIEW
{'depth': '1', 'prompt': '${KHOSTNAME}(config-if)# ', 'name': 'configure-range-view'}
{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}VIEW
{'name': 'configure-view'}
```

I can't seem to get any data from below `configure-view`, any ideas?

I also tried:

```
for neighbor in root.iter('VIEW'):
    print neighbor.attrib

for i in root.findall('COMMAND'):
    print i
    rank = i.find('help').text
    name = i.get('name')
    print name, rank
```

and changing the root:

```
root = ET.Element("COMMAND")
```

Nothing gets printed out.

Comment: Your code does exactly the same thing on both xml documents: it goes through all immediate children of the root.

Comment: Your XML contains namespaced tags; you need to qualify the namespace when using `findall()` or `iter()`. See the duped post.

Comment: @Marcin So basically I have to search configure-view?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks I'll ahve a look, so bsaically I qualify configure-view.find-all or somesuch

Comment: @Paul It's not clear to me what you want to do. But if you want to get information about the children of that element, you'll need to find it first.

Comment: @Paul: See my answer there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes I want to be able to find the whole document, address each part, then I could write this whole file to a new file as an initial test. I just want to have everything addressable. Basically I'm trying to autogenerate code from existing code, so i need to be able to read it and choose what I want in a  new file. I'm trying to understand your answer at the moment, thank you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Trying it out but can't seem to print out anything still, will have another look. I need to do a lot more reading. `namespaces = {'configure-view'} 
print root.findall('COMMAND', namespaces=namespaces)`

Comment: Your `namespaces` dictionary is a set, not a dictionary. You need to set a value: `namespaces = {'c': 'http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema'}` associates the prefix `c` with the namespace I see in your post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah I'm not really getting this, whether I use c or not I cant find any data. And c.findall gives an error etc `namespaces = {'c': 'http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema'}
print root.findall('c:configure-view', namespaces=namespaces)

for i in root.findall('c:name', namespaces=namespaces):
    print i`

Comment: May I ask, if I wanted to print out `interface range` from my file, what is the syntax?